# How can I build sigma-ring that is not sigma-algebra

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Sigma-algebra is a sigma-ring with a unit. By definition, sigma-ring is a ring of sets which is closed under countable unions.

How can a sigma-ring don't have a unit? Or can I get a unit that can't be consist of countable unions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are saying that unit means that it contains $X$.

So you are looking for a collection of sets $\mathcal{A} \subset \mathcal P(X)$ such that $X \not \in \mathcal A$, while $\mathcal A$ is still closed under countable unions and relative complementation ($A, B \in \mathcal A \implies A\setminus B \in \mathcal A$).

Let $X = \{0,1,2\}$ and $\mathcal A = \{\{0,1\},\emptyset\}$.  Clearly $\mathcal A$ satisfies the requirements of a $\sigma-ring$, though is not a $\sigma-algebra$.

For a more concrete example, consider the collection all null Lebesgue measurable sets.

Comment: To my understanding, A={{0,1},∅} is a σ−ring, yes. A is a system of set, and {0,1} is the unit of A. so A is a σ−algebra. I don't know what it has to do with X? Or my understanding about the defination of σ−algebra/unit is wrong?

Comment: OK, but his second example works.

Comment: A ring of sets $A$ is defined as a collection of **subsets of $X$**. If the ring $A$ contains $X$ it is considered an algebra. If the ring is closed under countable unions, it is considered a $\sigma-ring$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sigma ring of countable subsets of $\mathbb R$.